# How to add a new OID to a x509 using phpseclib?

Tags: x509, phpseclib, oid

I'm really new to this certificates world.
I need to add a custom OID to a x509 certificate using phpseclib. This one will be just a string value.

Ex.: `2.16.76.1.10.1 = SOME_STRING_VALUE`

Sorry if I'm not clear enough...

Comment: (Assuming you're running 3.0,) does `ASN1::loadOIDs(['SOME_STRING_VALUE' => '2.16.76.1.10.1']);` do what you want? You'd prob need to do that before you load the X509 cert.

Comment: Exactly, I'm running version 3.0. It worked.